# How to convert excel individual cell values to percentage change values over time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two years of excel data showing daily share prices of a particular stock. I want to change those values to show percentage change (on a daily basis) from the zero date (ie the first day of the two year period). I know that the formula for showing daily percentage change would be (second day/first day -1) and that I can click and drag on that formula to extend over the rest of the two-year time period. The formula I want would be, basically, (each day/first day-1). Is there an easy way to automate the script so I dont have to type it out 730 times?

Comment: Use the **$** in your formula to fix the proper cell reference so it does not change as the formula is being dragged down.

Answer (score 1):

After you've set up the first formula with an absolute reference in the denominator (`=A2/$A$-1` or `=A2/A$1-1`) as recommended by Gary's Student and Raystafarian, rather than dragging the formula down 700 cells you can use keyboard shortcuts to quickly copy and paste the formula into column `B`.

Assuming your data are in cells `A1:A700` and you want to copy the cumulative percent change formula to cells `B2:B700`:

**Alternative A**

- Enter the percentage formula in cell `B2` and copy it using the `Control-C` key combination.
- Move over to cell `A2` and then press the `Control` and `Down-Arrow` keys at the same time to move to cell `A700`.
- Move over to cell `B700` and then select the range `B2:B700` by first pressing the `Control` and `Shift` key-combination. With the keys still held down, press the `Up-Arrow` key.
- Finally, release the keys and then press the `Enter` key to paste the formula into the highlighted cells.

  This method sounds pretty elaborate when described in words, but is lightning quick in practice.

**Alternative B**

- As in alternative A, enter the percentage change formula and copy it using `Control-C`.
- Press the `F5` key to open the `Go To` dialog box. Type in the address `B700` in the `Reference` entry box and press `Enter` to jump to `B700`.
- To finish up, press the `Up-Arrow` key while holding down the `Control` and `Shift` keys to select the range `B2:B700`. Release the key-combination and press the `Enter` key to paste the formula into the highlighted cells.

Answer (score 0):

if the first day of data is in A1 and then subsequent days are in column A, then in B2 you would put `=A2/$A$1-1` so when you drag it down B column, the *relative reference* of `A2` will change, but the *absolute reference* of `$A$1` will not change.

Learn a little more on cell references [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/relative.aspx)